# Does macOS have equivalent command line tools like `lshw` or `lspci` for enumerating PCI hardware devices?

Tags: macos, command-line, software-recommendation, system-information

The closest thing I know of is `system_profiler` but it spits out way too much unnecessary information and I don't have a good way to filter / transform that output.

What's the closest alternative to something like `lshw` or  `lspci` on  Mac OS X?

Comment: Have you tried `sysctl`? I think `sysctl machdep` gives some information pertaining to your machine.

Comment: @perhapsmaybeharry Nice suggestion with `sysctl`. Not quite what I'm looking for though.

Comment: Why not `awk | grep | sed ` out the undesired information? `system_profiler` and `ioreg` are the canonical tools to enumerate hardware details on macOS.

Comment: @bmike I do, for the most part, or when I need to.

Comment: `dmidecode` is also abandoned :(

Answer (score 17):

Try parsing the output of the `ioreg` command.

I tried `ioreg -l | grep PCI` and got a bunch of info.

Answer (score 2):

`system_profiler` can look quite daunting in terms of detail and categories of information - it is after all basically a command line version of MacOS System Report tool. But it can be quite easily filtered by specifying *DataTypes* you want to list and *detailLevel* for each dataType

**Examples of dataTypes that can provide you with the similar information as `lshw` and `lspci`:**

`system_profiler SPHardwareDataType SPMemoryDataType SPPCIDataType SPAudioDataType`

As most modern Macs have most of the peripherals connected via **Thunderbolt and USB**, here's the detailed version of both:

`system_profiler SPThunderboltDataType SPUSBDataType`

**Storage information:**

`system_profiler SPNVMeDataType SPSerialATADataType SPStorageDataType`

**Network information:**

`system_profiler SPNetworkDataType SPEthernetDataType SPAirPortDataType SPBluetoothDataType`

**There are further formatting options:**

- `-json` for JSON output (and than you can use something like `jq` to your heart's content)
- `-xml` for XML output
- `detailLevel [level]` mini/basic/full for level of detail

**You can also list all available dataTypes by:**

`system_profiler -listDataTypes`

---

**Source:** `man system_profiler`, MacOS System Manager's Manual

Answer (score 1):

For those familiar with Docker, a simple workaround is to run a simple ubuntu container, and install lshw in there. I have found it to work great.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try ***`dspci`*** console utility from the open-source [DPCIManager project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dpcimanager/). **I must warn you** though, that the software is coming from the Hackintosh/OSx86 world and the DPCIManager.app offers extra functionality in addition to listing PCI devices that is **not at all safe to run on a real Mac**, so please avoid using anything from that package except the ***`dspci`*** utility which only does listing PCI devices in your system (like *`lspci`* in Linux).

Comment: That sounds like it would be good; if it was native. I think you're kind of on the right track, though. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: FYI: `lshw`, `lspci`, `lsusb`, etc. are all available from external sources too.

Comment: @tjt263, right, there are both macOS ports of pciutils and libusb (I suspect that `lspci` and `lsusb` are included in the respective source trees as examples/handy utils). There are also wrapper shells available that use e.g. `system_profiler SPUSBDataType` as a datasource and try to behave like `lsusb` or whatever.

Comment: That's right. I do recall the `lsusb` package distributed via `brew`, basically being just a wrapper, clone, or alias for something like `system_profiler SPUSBDataType`.

Comment: @tjt263 brew says :


```No formula found for "/pciutil/".
No formula found for "/lshw/".
No formula found for "/lsusb/".
No formula found for "/lspci/".```


Where ? Can you please be more precise and give URLs ?

Comment: updated version of dspci: https://github.com/MuntashirAkon/DPCIManager

Answer (score -1):

#### system_profiler

The best I could find was `system_profiler` but it's way too detailed for me (I was hoping for something like `dmidecode` which hasn't been maintained since 2017).

Credits: https://osxdaily.com/2007/04/23/get-system-information-from-the-command-line/